# I built a C++ program on Windows, how can I compile an executable for MacOS?

Tags: c++, macos, compilation, executable

I have built a little C++ program on Windows, and I'd like to share it with some people, but they are on MacOS. What tools can I use to compile an executable (like .exe for Windows) and share the project to them? If needed, I have a MacOS VM.

Comment: What tools did you use to build it? Can it run from a command line or does it use system UI elements (windows, buttons...)?

Comment: That is a very good point. If you used the windows api directly you may have to resort having the people you share use [wine](https://wiki.winehq.org/MacOS) or you may have to completely rewrite your application using a cross platform GUI. If this is just a console application with no winapi dependency it could just be a matter of compiling using xcode.

Comment: If you've installed Xcode, you can compile your code with Xcode as an IDE using an Xcode project, or you can compile it on the command line.  If you don't have Xcode installed, you'll need to install a compiler such as Xcode, or gcc, or clang.

Comment: @PhillipMills This is a CLI project, and it uses only standard libraries

Comment: Xcode is very large but includes everything you need.  If you want a stripped-down build environment for CLI building, you can try something like: https://mac-how-to.gadgethacks.com/how-to/install-command-line-developer-tools-without-xcode-0168115/

Comment: @PhillipMills I already have Xcode on my laptop so I can use it. But I don’t really know how to create the executable file to distribute with Xcode... And I am maybe very bad at searching, but I don’t find much on Google...

Comment: Create a new Xcode project.  Select macOS and Command Line Tool.  Fill in the product name and choose C++ language. Save somewhere.  That should get you a project with a dummy "main.cpp".  Add and replace source files as necessary.  Use Product->Build menu (or Command-B) to create the executable.

Comment: @PhillipMills it worked, but when I share the executable on another Mac, it can’t open it because the developer cannot be verified...

Comment: @PhillipMills ok I found. I have to control click on the file and then click on open. Thank you for your help! If you post an answer, I’ll validate it!

Comment: Right...that's a system security setting, not a build one.  If you were doing a lot of this, you'd want an account with Apple and go through steps to have your app notarized for Catalina.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build your sources with Xcode. Or try to run .exe with WINE (https://www.winehq.org/)